# Datanode is not starting after deploying Hadoop cluster 2.6

Tags: linux, hadoop, apache-spark, redhat

```
ERROR received in the logs:
FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to hadooptest3/100.6.89.29:8020
```

Comment: please add more part of the log and if possible share your config files too.

Comment: 17/06/14 05:58:19 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /home/hadoop/hdfs/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 10382@hadooptest3
17/06/14 05:58:19 WARN common.Storage:org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.IncorrectVersionException: Unexpected version of storage directory /home/hadoop/hdfs. Reported: -60. Expecting = -56.
17/06/14 05:58:19 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to hadooptest3/100.6.89.29:8020. Exiting.

Comment: java.io.IOException: All specified directories are failed to load.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataStorage.recoverTransitionRead(DataStorage.java:478)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initStorage(DataNode.java:1342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.initBlockPool(DataNode.java:1308)

Comment: Core-site.xml: <configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadooptest3/</value>
    <description>NameNode URI</description>
  </property>
</configuration>

Comment: **Slaves** : [hadoop@hadooptest3 hadoop]$ cat slaves
hadooptest3
hadooptest4

Comment: **Yarn-site.xml** : <configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>hadooptest3</value>
  <description>The hostname of the ResourceManager</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
  <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
  <description>shuffle service for MapReduce</description>
</property>
<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->
</configuration>

Comment: **mapred-site.xml** : <configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
  <description>Execution framework.</description>
</property>
</configuration>

Comment: **hdfs-site.xml** : <configuration>
<property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/</value>
        <description>DataNode directory for storing data chunks.</description>
    </property>

    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/</value>
        <description>NameNode directory for namespace and transaction logs storage.</description>
    </property>

Comment: _continued_ **hdfs-site.xml** : <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>3</value>
        <description>Number of replication for each chunk.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: @DevTorvalds please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 Possible Solutions to resolve

First:

```
Your namenode and datanode cluster ID does not match, make sure to make them the same.
```

In name node, change your cluster id in the file located in:

```
cat HADOOP_FILE_SYSTEM/namenode/current/VERSION
```

In data node you cluster id is stored in the file:

```
cat HADOOP_FILE_SYSTEM/datanode/current/VERSION
```

This locations are set in hdfs-site.xml file in the cluster.

Check your hdfs-site.xml file and check for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `dfs.namenode.name.dir`.

By going through those folders, Here I get the contents (in my pseudo-cluster)

```
clusterID=CID-483c19b1-b198-4806-93d2-af7508d1a5e5
```

You should have exactly same cluster-id.

Secondly:

Format the namenode:

```
Hadoop 1.x: hadoop namenode -format

Hadoop 2.x: hdfs namenode -format
```

---

Alternatively, remove hdfs root directory `/tmp/hadoop-root/` (set up in conf files) - and format the namenode to initialize from begining.

Comment: 1.datanode and namenode cluster ID was mismatching before. I matched it. Still it didnt work. So will it be changed from datanode to namenode or from namenode to datanode, hdfs-site.xml is not having those details in my configuration. 2. I tried formatting those but it didnt help and I dont have /tmp/hadoop-root/ but having /tmp/hadoop-hadoop as I access hadoop with hadoop user , not the root user.

Comment: Check your `hdfs-site.xml` file and check for `dfs.datanode.data.dir` and `dfs.namenode.name.dir`.

And by going through those folders, Here I get the contents (in my pseudo-cluster)


    `clusterID=CID-483c19b1-b198-4806-93d2-af7508d1a5e5`


You should have exactly same cluster-id.

  Or delete the `/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/` folder and format the namenode

Comment: ok. So I did that deletion and formatted. But I think that in _hdfs-site.xml_ I  have given dfs.datanode.data.dir and dfs.namenode.name.dir as same only , Is it fine?  Cluster ID is same in both the machines now. But I have copied the whole **VERSION** file from _namenode_ to _datanode_. Is there any problem?

Comment: those dir paths can be same. You should only copy/replace the `cluster-id` line; not the following line in that file.

Comment: Ok. let me check with the cluster-id thing now. Is it like deleting **VERSION** file in datanode will recreate it again after _HADOOP NAMENODE FORMAT_ and _HDFS NAMENODE FORMAT_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Your config files looks fine. From the error logs that you commented `Unexpected version of storage directory /home/hadoop/hdfs. Reported: -60. Expecting = -56.` , it seems that `data` directory created inside `/home/hadoop/hdfs` **is not reformated** when you applied `hadoop namenode -format command.

So I suggest you to `delete` that `data` directory inside `/home/hadoop/hdfs` before you `format` `namenode`. Then apply `format` command and start `hadoop` cluster. It should be solved then.